# how setOnKeyListener works

Tags: java, android, keylistener

we got homework to make convertor of weights where the fields are updated while typing the number (no need to click "calculate" or anything). one of the students offered the code below.
the code works: when putting a number in field 1, field 2 changes while typing.

what i dont understand is how does that work?
in the `onKey` method, no value is given to `View` `int` and `keyEvent`
so how does the listener "knows" on which view to and what keys to listen to or what event to activate ?

```
public class Screen extends Activity {
double weight = 2.20462;
EditText kgEdit, lbsEdit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    kgEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.kgEdit);
    lbsEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lbsEdit);

    kgEdit.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            String kg = kgEdit.getText().toString();
            if (kg.isEmpty()) {
                lbsEdit.setText("");
            } else {
                double num = Double.valueOf(kgEdit.getText().toString()) * weight;
                lbsEdit.setText(num + "");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    lbsEdit.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            String lbs = lbsEdit.getText().toString();
            if (lbs.isEmpty()) {
                kgEdit.setText("");
            } else {
                double num = Double.valueOf(lbsEdit.getText().toString()) / weight;
                kgEdit.setText(num + "");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Take a look at Official Documentation about [onKeyListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html) and [listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/) in general.

Comment: Uhm well, he creates a new Listener for both edittexts so he doesn't have to bother which edit text got an event, because the code for this specific edit text is already in the actual listener.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to focus on just 1 of the text fields to answer this. Look at this first line:

`kgEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.kgEdit);`

All this does is get a reference to the `EditText` for entering kg. Now that there is a reference, we can call methods on that object.

Next, we have this:

```
kgEdit.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

What the above does is the following. Take our reference to the `EditText` for kilograms that we retrieved in our first line. The method `setOnKeyListener` does the following (from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnKeyListener(android.view.View.OnKeyListener))): "Register a callback to be invoked when a hardware key is pressed in this view."

What this means is that you've now told the view that you want to be informed every time the user presses a key while this EditText has the focus. You make this call to the Android API and in the background Android handles everything you're asking. It will call the method with the `View view`, `int keyCode` and `KeyEvent event`. You give it a method that then handles those inputs. So nowhere in your code do you need to call the method, Android calls it in the background where you'll never have to see or worry about it.

Now, because you called the method on `kgEdit`, that means the following code will ONLY be called when `kgEdit` is focused and keys are typed, so there's no confusion with the other `EditText`. It gets its own method call later, just below. Here's the rest of the code inside the `setOnKeyListener`:

```
String kg = kgEdit.getText().toString();
if (kg.isEmpty()) {
    lbsEdit.setText("");
} else {
    double num = Double.valueOf(kgEdit.getText().toString()) * weight;
    lbsEdit.setText(num + "");
}

return false;
```

What this does is get the current text in `kgEdit`, which has already been updated with the key the user pressed. And it just checks if the text is empty, and if so remove the text in `lbsEdit`. If it's not empty, then get the text, convert it to a number, convert the number from kg to lbs and update `lbsEdit`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use addTextChangedListener like this-

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //do here your calculation
            String data = s.toString();
        }
    });
```